# Make a content <DIV> fill the container with a variable height header

Tags: css, layout, html

I feel like I shouldn't be asking such a simple question but I can't find any simple answers out there.

I have a header  which can be any height. The content  beneath it needs to fill up the remaining space on the page (Both are contained in a necessary container div). How can this be achieved with HTML and CSS? I would consider JavaScript but I want resizing to be automatic when content is added, or the window is resized etc.

HTML code:

```
<div id="container" >

    <div id="header" >
      <br/>
      <br/>
      ...variable content in the header (not necessarily text)...
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </div>

    <div id="content"></div>

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#container
{
  background-color:blue; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
}

#header
{
  background-color:green;
  width:100%; 
  height:auto;
}

#content
{
  background-color:red; 
  width:100%;
  height:100px; /*The height here needs to fill the remaining space in the container div*/
}
```

Comment: You can't self close a DIV so your "content" DIV needs a closing DIV tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may help do what you want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/AGLDV/3/

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

#container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#ccc;
  display:table;
}

#header {
  height:1%;
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
  display:table-row;
}

#content {
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  display:table-row;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this example has a **fixed** height header. My header height can be variable.

Comment: @user1282944 - The header doesn't have to be fixed. I only gave it a height for the sake of giving it a height to illustrate. Remove the height and it will still work.

Comment: I removed the height and it just displays both the header and content taking up half the height each.

Comment: @user1282944 - See my amended code above. I've given it an initial height of 1% now and that will expand when more content is added.

Comment: I set the height to 0px, removed the html and body from the css and it worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGLDV/2/)

I set the header height to `height: auto;` and then added `overflow: hidden;` to the `body, html` style.

Just add any text or `<br />` in the header and the height will change.

Comment: This cuts off the content div rather than stretching it